# What are the differences between private IPv4 and public IPv4?

Tags: networking, ip, ip-address

If possible please mention where these where these IP addresses are used and state the range of public IP address

Comment: The _only_ difference between public and private IPv4 addresses is that the ISPs have agreed to not route private IP addresses on the public Internet. This is an artificial limitation, and the private IP address ranges were rather arbitrarily chosen. There is nothing about the IP protocol which creates a distinction between public and private IP addresses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer** is that the private ip-range cannot be routed in the internet.
But everyone can use these ranges in private network.Configure routing for internal needs.
You can use NAT If user needs to get access to internet.

**More details about routing and internet:**
Each ip range is fixed to some owner.
We have a few organization that provides these ranges i.e. [RIPE](https://www.ripe.net).
Each owher provides different document and gets [AS number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(Internet))
Then RIPE (or other organization) set the new range for the AS.
The AS number and information from RIPE are used to route network traffic.
There are BGP protcol is used
All internet providers filters the private ip ranges.

Notes: 
1. What organization provides ip-range is depends on geographical location of the company that requests this range
2. As far as I know you cannot get a new IPv4 range now. All Ipv4 ranges already are used.
3. You can get IPv6 range.

Comment: I hope it'll help you. Lets ask me if you need more details